# Where is object, property or label in the database that controls the order of the posts being displayed?

Tags: posts, order

I'm trying to update the database once the user has re ordered the posts via a draggable js plugin whilst is_user_logged_in(). I'll probably have a save button on the front end (in logged in mode of course) but i can't find where and what to write to the databse when it updates the re-ordering of posts that are displayed in a grid format on the home page.

Comment: Posts are, by default, ordered in reverse chronological order. Unless you want to change the actual date of the post - which you probably do not - then you need to change the main query itself, and add your own ordering custom field.

Comment: you have to store the order value as a [custom field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) then order by [`meta_value`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).